# While importing sql table getting error due to collation

Tags: mysql, sql, database

the code for creating  table  is given below while i try to import this table in new database am getting the following error

**Query**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blogs` (
  `blog_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `blog_title` text NOT NULL,
  `blog_content` text NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `updated_on` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`blog_id`)
) Engine=InnoDB  AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
```

> error:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '(6) NOT NULL,   `created_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
>   `updated_on` datetime(6) NOT NU' at line 11

kindly guide me to solve this issues still i need to import many tables

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: remove length (6) from datetime column definition

Comment: mysql version version 5.5

Comment: The question has nothing to do with php, that's why i have removed the tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove length **(6)** from `datetime(6)`.

So your query would look something like this,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blogs` (
  `blog_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `blog_title` text NOT NULL,
  `blog_content` text NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `updated_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`blog_id`)
) Engine=InnoDB  AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can not specify length attribute to datetime column:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blogs` (
  `blog_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `blog_title` text NOT NULL,
  `blog_content` text NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `updated_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`blog_id`)
) Engine=InnoDB  AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't set length in `datetime` .Just use it as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blogs` (
  `blog_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `blog_title` text NOT NULL,
  `blog_content` text NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,// remove length here
  `created_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `updated_on` datetime NOT NULL,// remove length here
  `updated_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`blog_id`)
)Engine=InnoDB  AUTO_INCREMENT=14
```

Comment: Yes what is the problem in that??Or better it would be  BIGINT

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you are using length 6 in your Datetime fields.
Remove length and it will be okay.

Answer (score 0):

When using MySQL 5.5 it results in an error when adding a length to datetime, so for this to work you would have to write

```
REATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blogs` (
  `blog_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `blog_title` text NOT NULL,
  `blog_content` text NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `updated_on` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`blog_id`)
) Engine=InnoDB  AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
```

This however will work when using MySQL 5.6. 
It will not add the length to `datetime`, but MySQL 5.6 will ignore the length and execute it as a normal `datetime` field.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all for your suggestions  now its working for me

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blogs` (
  `blog_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `blog_title` text NOT NULL,
  `blog_content` text NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `updated_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`blog_id`)
) Engine=InnoDB  AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
```

when we use datetime in the table it will automatically allocate memory size so we don't need to specify it